In scala 3, how to implement an implicit conversion over a type refined by iron?
Here is a minimal not working example of what I am trying to do :
Let
import io.github.iltotore.iron.*
import io.github.iltotore.iron.constraint.string.*

case class User(name: String)
type Username = String :| StartWith["@"]
def name2user(usern : Username) : User = User(usern)

I want to implements an implicit conversion so that  :
val user : User = "@john" //compile
val user : User = "!john" //not compile

Here what I've tried so far
given name2user: Conversion[Username, User] = User(_)
val user1 : User = name2user("@john") // 
val user2 : User = "@john" //does not compile because "@john" is a String

and
implicit def name2user[S <: String](n: S)(implicit
   ev: S <:< Username
): User = User(n)
val user1: User = name2user2("@john") // cannot prove that String <:< Username
val user2: User = "@john" // does not compile because "@john" is a String

Once again this is a minimal example to illustrate as simply as possible my objective to integrate Iron's refinements and Scala 3 implicit conversions.
Thank you in anticipation for your help

Do you want the conversion to happen with literal values? If so, that already exists and is part of the library. If you want it to happen with arbitrary strings, then you can't really return an User but rather something like Either[Error, User] and I would not recommend making that a conversion.

Also, looking at your example, it feels wrong. You are dropping the refinement. What exactly is the meta-problem you are trying to solve?

Comments from the staging are not visible here so: the meta problem was that autor didn't want to have Iron in their types but wanted to use it to automatically generate compile time validation while lifting literals to their types. And it can be done with implicit inline defs instead of Conversion.

Okay, that makes sense. I still think is kind of weird tho.

In a nutshell, conversion are kind of compile time functions. Whereas refinement are kind of compile time validation. I wanted to integrate both tools to obtain compile time validation of function, or in other words, compile time partial functions.This appear to be really straightforward to do in scala 3…

Answering, you should inline and typelevel programming using good old implicits  :
implicit inline def name2user(inline n: String)
(implicit inline ev: Username = n): User = User(n)   

val user3: User = name2user("@john") // compile   
val user4: User = "@john" // compile  
val user5: User = "#john" // does not compile as it should 

An interesting variation is to declare
case class User(name: Username)
implicit inline def name2user(inline n: String)
(implicit inline ev: Username = n): User = User(ev)   

This guarantee User is always well formed while authorizing a compile time automatic construction of it from well formed strings.
